How to bind trigger parameters to appsettings.json under Isolated azure function
When running under the in-process function model, you could resolve trigger parameters from the appsettings.json - assuming its been configured as a custom configuration source as defined here.
e.g. The below timertrigger would resolve ScheduleTriggerTime from the appsettings.json file.
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%ScheduleTriggerTime%")]TimerInfo myTimer)

After moving to the isolated worker model, binding from appsettings.json no longer seems to work, I can only get it to work if the setting is in the local.settings.json file.
Example code below running under the isolated model, adding appsettings.json files to the configuration, and trying to get the trigger setting ScheduleTriggerTime from said appsettings files for the TimerTrigger. Upon starting the app the error "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%ScheduleTriggerTime%' does not resolve to a value." is thrown.
Program.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            configurationBuilder
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
    .Build();

host.Run();


Function1.cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("%ScheduleTriggerTime%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
        }
    }
}

appsettings.json
{
  "ScheduleTriggerTime": "0 */1 * * * *"
}

Is this an intentional change under the isolated model, or am I missing something to make this resolve the setting from the appsettings.json file?

Set the schedule expression as an app setting in local.settings.json and use this property in function code by wrapping with % sign i.e., %ScheduleTriggerTime%.

Created a .NET 8.0 Isolated Azure function and configured scheduleTime application setting as shown below:

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "scheduledtime": "0 */5 * * * *"
  }
}

Function Code:
[Function("Function1")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger("%scheduledtime%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            
    if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
    {
    _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
    }
}


Response:
[2024-07-12T08:36:56.883Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 4276) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-07-12T08:36:56.964Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-07-12T08:37:01.933Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-07-12T08:40:00.087Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-07-12T14:10:00.0501505+05:30', Id=7a8cadcc-50fb-45e2-8f82-73188095026d)
[2024-07-12T08:40:08.505Z] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 7/12/2024 2:10:08 PM
[2024-07-12T08:40:08.505Z] Next timer schedule at: 7/12/2024 2:10:00 PM
[2024-07-12T08:40:08.534Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=7a8cadcc-50fb-45e2-8f82-73188095026d, Duration=8472ms)


As mentioned in the question, I already know this works when the setting is in the local.settings.json. What I want to know if its possible to make it work with the setting in the appsettings.json file. This used to work under the in-porcess model.

I have tried using appsettings.json, looks like it doesn't support and local.settings.json is the only way to achieve your requirement.
